# Função Keyboard não funciona PyOpenGL

Tags: python, funções, opengl, pyopengl

Galera eu tenho o seguinte código, queria fazer um simples evento para fechar a aplicação mas minha função keyboard não funciona, procurei em outros lugares e encontrei versões parecidas. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *

import OpenGL.GL
import sys, struct



def desenha():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glPointSize(5.0)
    glBegin(GL_POINTS)
    glColor3fv((0,1,0))
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glColor3fv((1,0,1))
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.1, 0.0)
    glColor3fv((1,0,1))
    glVertex3f(0.1, 0.0, 0.0)
    glColor3fv((1,0,1))
    glVertex3f(0.0, -0.1, 0.0)
    glColor3fv((1,0,1))
    glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.0, 0.0)

    glEnd()
    glutSwapBuffers()

def keyboard(key, x, y):
    if key == chr(97):
        sys.exit(0)
    return 0


def main():
    glutInit([])
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB| GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA)
    #glutInitWindowSize(400,400)
    glutCreateWindow(b'This is my title')
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
    glutDisplayFunc(desenha)
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard)

    glutCreateMenu(nome)
    glutMainLoop()


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [documentação da glutkeyboardFunc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glutKeyboardFunc.html) em

diz que a assinatura da função de tratamento do teeclado é:

```
def handler( (int) key, (int) x, (int) y ):
    return None
```

Ou seja, você recebe o código numérico da tecla (um número) - e no seu cpódigo você compara esse número com um caractere - (o resultado da chamada a `chr(97)` que no caso é uma string com a letra `"a"`). O resultado disso é
sempre falso. Talvez você tenha visto algum código de exemplo em C 
onde o casting `(char)97` é essencialmente uma "no operation" - internamente o seu dado continua sendo o número 97.

Em Python, ou você compara os números diretamente -

```
if key == 97
```

Ou, para melhorar a legibilidade, compara o caractére representado pelo código recebido com o caractére desejado. Ou seja: você transforma o número recebido em caractére:

if chr(key) == "a":
        ...

Se optar por essa forma a um detalhe a mais - o código recebido pode estar fora da faixa 0-255, e ai a chamada à `chr` daria um erro - então, certifique-se de que o código numérico está nessa faixa:

```
def keyboard(key, x, y):
    if 0 <= key <= 255 and chr(key) == "a":
        sys.exit(0)
    return None
```

(note que também é interessante deixar o valor de retorno como None, como está sugerido na documentação. Em Python, isso é diferente de retornar "0" - que talvez você também tenha visto em algum exemplo em C)